# Order of different collection type in java?

Tags: collections

Just wanted to confirm the in what order we get the elements from different collection

**List**

ArrayList:- the sequence in which we put the element we get them in same sequence

LinkedList:- when we add an element in linked list with add(E e) it will be added at last when we get it with itertator it will start from first element to last element. So we can say
the sequence in which we put the element we get them in reverse sequence

**Set**

HashSet:- No sequence(for getting the elemnets) is guaranted. It will be a random sequence

Tresset:- Will get the elements as per their natural ordering or comparator defined at the time of creation

**Map**

HashMap:- No sequence(for getting the elemnets) is guaranted. It will be a random sequence

TreeMap:- Will get the elements as per their natural ordering of key or comparator defined at the time of creation

Please let me know if it is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup - apart from your use of the word *random*. The order from a hash set/map won't actually be random; it will just be implementation-specific and unpredicatable. Not quite the same thing - in particular, you shouldn't use it as a source of randomness - but you're right that you shouldn't rely on it being any *specific* ordering.

Answer (score 0):

This ordering is what you would get if you used an iterator. I think the Java Doc are clear enough for this to be apparent. Mind you this is not all on one page.